# MYSQL TRIGGER with IF condition

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm a noob im MYSQL and I'm trying to make a trigger who will auto-fill 2 fields(customername, customersurname) in an invoice table. Can anyoane explain me please what I do wrong in that trigger? Thank you very much! :)

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
  customerID INT(6) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customername VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  customersurname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  customeraddress VARCHAR(200)
);

CREATE TABLE invoice(
  invoiceID INT (6) Primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customerID INT (6) REFERENCES customer(customerID),
  customername VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES customer(customername), 
  invoicedate DATE,
  orderID INT(6) REFERENCES orders(orderID),
  products VARCHAR(200) REFERENCES orderlines(productname),
  FOREIGN KEY(orderID) REFERENCES orders(orderID)
);

CREATE TRIGGER autofill_invoice BEFORE INSERT ON invoice FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN 
IF (new.customerID = customer.customerID,
    new.customersurname = customer.customersurname ) 
THEN 
     SET new.customername = customer.customername,
         new.customersurname = customer.customersurname;         
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: you don't have `customersurname` column in `invoice` table

Comment: didn't see that. thank mitkosoft :)

Comment: just realized I already altered the invoice table and added the customersurname field :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mysql documentation on [defining stored programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) explains:

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command. The
>   following example shows how to do this for the dorepeat() procedure
>   just shown. The delimiter is changed to // to enable the entire
>   definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then
>   restored to ; before invoking the procedure. This enables the ;
>   delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the
>   server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.

So, use the delimiter command when you define the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER autofill_invoice BEFORE INSERT ON invoice FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN 
IF (new.customerID = customer.customerID,
    new.customersurname = customer.customersurname ) 
THEN 
     SET new.customername = customer.customername,
         new.customersurname = customer.customersurname;         
END IF;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Next time pls provide exact error description in your question!

Comment: Thank you Shadow. I received an error from the HeidiSQl client telling me that something is wrong in that syntax, but HeidySQL/MariaDB is not very specific on error reporting.
Now, the trigger is working perfect :).
Thanks again and have a great day!

Comment: Glad to be able to help. If the above response helped you to resolve the error, then pls mark the answer as accepted, so other viewer will know that the question has been resolved.